# Prevent swipe triggering tap

Tags: javascript, ios, hammer.js

I have a dropdown menu on the mobile version of my site. I am attaching handlers for the singletap and doubletap gestures. All other gestures I want to default to their normal behavior. No matter what I try, the beginning of a swipe or pan is triggering the singletap event and responding accordingly. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var menuLinks1 = document.querySelectorAll(".menu.level1 a.item");
    for (var i = 0; i < menuLinks1.length; i++) {
      var menuLink1 = menuLinks1[i];
      if (menuLink1) {
        var hammerMgr = new Hammer.Manager(menuLink1);

        hammerMgr.add(new Hammer.Tap({ event: "doubletap", taps: 2 }));
        hammerMgr.add(new Hammer.Tap({ event: "singletap" }));
        hammerMgr.add(new Hammer.Tap({ event: "pan" }));
        hammerMgr.add(new Hammer.Tap({ event: "swipe" }));

        hammerMgr.get("pan").set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL });

        hammerMgr.get("doubletap").recognizeWith("singletap");
        hammerMgr.get("singletap").requireFailure("doubletap");
        hammerMgr.get("singletap").requireFailure("pan");
        hammerMgr.get("singletap").requireFailure("swipe");

        hammerMgr.on("doubletap", function (e) {
          doubletapMenuItem(e);
        });

        hammerMgr.on("singletap", function (e) {
          toggleSubmenu(e);
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

What am I missing or doing wrong? How should I set this up so a swipe or pan doesn't trigger a tap?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't figure it out and didn't get any answers to my question, so switched to the SmartMenus and it's working great.